# trap "stty echo" INT has no effect when used with read -s

Tags: bash, signals, stty

Given this bash script:

```sh
stty -echo
echo $(stty)

reset() {
        stty echo
        echo $(stty)
        exit
}

trap reset int
read -s
sleep 10
```

I expected the echo option to be enabled, but after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> it is still disabled, even though I have ran `stty echo`  (as you can see in the output by the `reset` function).

[image: terminal picture]

Comment: No images please.

Comment: @Roadowl What's wrong with this one? The only thing I pasted in is `bash demo.sh`, pressed `ctrl+c` and ran `stty`.

Comment: What if you use `SIGINT`, not `int`.

Comment: You could have posted a transcript of the script running, marking it up as 'code' — preferably with triple-backquote and the word 'none' (which is very hard to demonstrate in a comment).

Comment: It can be useful to use `old=$(stty -g)` to capture the current terminal settings, and then use `stty "$old"` to reinstate those settings.  That's tangential to your question, though.  Since Bash is having to dink with the terminal settings to implement `read -s`, it probably has its own operations to reinstate the original state after it completes, even if the `read` command is interrupted.  I'd be surprised (but I haven't tested it) if Bash left the terminal in no-echo mode after `read -s` completed, even if it was interrupted.

Comment: @Roadowl IIRC the signal codes are case insensitive and the `sig` is optional when used in `trap`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, but I didn't want to make anybody think I executed `speed` and `line` commands. I don't think the image contains any useful text to be copied, it's just for the demonstration purposes.

Comment: [bash restores](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/read.def#L508) tty when read -s exits. I think the chain is: `read -s` starts, SIGINT trap executes, `read -s` restores flags, script terminates.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler then it seems like it's a bug in the `read` command. IMO it should accept modifications running in background.

Comment: @KamilCuk Any idea how to run `stty echo` after `read` finishes?

Comment: Note that if you use `read -s`, there is no need for you to mess with the terminal settings at all.  Just use `read -s` — it will handle no-echo mode and interrupts already.  You seem to be trying to solve a problem that doesn't need to be solved by you; Bash already takes care of it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's the way! Resetting `stty` before `read -s` and redoing the modifications afterwards works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KamilCuk [has noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334588/trap-stty-echo-int-has-no-effect-when-used-with-read-s?noredirect=1#comment119018118_67334588) in the comments, `read` saves the configuration and restores it when the process exists. That results in modifications done while `read` was running being discarded. The solution is to restore the defaults before running `read` and redoing them after `read` finishes.

```sh
stty -echo
echo $(stty)

reset() {
        stty echo
        echo $(stty)
        exit
}

trap reset int

stty echo # This line has been added
read -s
echo read finished
stty -echo # This line has been added

sleep 10
```

---

@JonathanLeffler also [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334588/trap-stty-echo-int-has-no-effect-when-used-with-read-s?noredirect=1#comment119017911_67334588) that

> It can be useful to use `old=$(stty -g)` to capture the current terminal settings, and then use `stty "$old"` to reinstate those settings.

[Explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334588/trap-stty-echo-int-has-no-effect-when-used-with-read-s?noredirect=1#comment119027858_67340145):

> Using it allows you to reinstate the exact terminal settings when `stty -g` was invoked. This can be more reliable than undoing changes with `stty -echo` etc.

Which I think is the more proper solution, as the `stty` may run in no-echo mode by default.

Comment: You might care to note what I said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334588/trap-stty-echo-int-has-no-effect-when-used-with-read-s?noredirect=1#comment119017911_67334588) about `stty -g`.  Using it allows you to reinstate the exact terminal settings when `stty -g` was invoked.  This can be more reliable than undoing changes with `stty -echo` etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're totally right. Edited :)